# Paginação com ajax

Tags: php, ajax, paginação

Tenho um código de paginação normal, está funcionando corretamente, mas não estou conseguindo inserir ajax na paginação.

Na verdade como estou usando funções, não sei como chamar a função "paginglink" na url do AJAX

Outro ponto é que o código tem `$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` que retorna a url atual, como substituo a variavel `$self` no links da paginação ao usar o Ajax?

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC";       
        $records_per_page=7;
        $newquery = $crud->paging($query,$records_per_page);
        $crud->dataview($newquery);
     ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7" align="center">
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
            <?php $crud->paginglink($query,$records_per_page); ?>
            </nav>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

class.crud.php

```
public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
    {

        $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($total_no_of_records > 0)
        {
            ?><ul class="pagination"><?php
            $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);
            $current_page=1;
            if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
            {
                $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
            }
            if($current_page!=1)
            {
                $previous =$current_page-1;
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".$self."?page_no=1'>First</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Back</a></li>";

            }
            for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($i==$current_page)
                {
                    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;'>".$i."</a></li>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
                }
            }
            if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
            {
                $next=$current_page+1;
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."'>Next</a></li>";
                echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".$self."?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a></li>";
            }
            ?></ul><?php
        }
    }
```

Ajax:

```
<script>
             $.ajax({  
                    url:"???",  
                    method:"POST",  
                    data:,  
                    success: ;  
                    }  
               }) 
    </script>
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` retorna a url atual. Se você manda a requisição via ajax, e no Ajax a função é chamada, a url atual será a url do Ajax. Não entendi qual é o problema. Poderia detalhar melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer fazer a paginação via ajax, sugiro uma pequena edição no seu código.

No trecho onde você coloca o link com o número da url no `href`, eu colocaria num `data-href` e pegaria esse valor via Javascript.

Exemplo:

```
"<a href='#' class='page-link' data-href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Back</a>";
```

Agora, ao invés de fazer a requisição normalmente pelo click no link com `href`, você poderia adicionar uma função jQuery, para fazer a requisição ajax para a url que está em `data-href`. Por exemplo:

```
$('.page-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).data('href');

   $.ajax({
         url: url,

         success: function (response) {
              $('#conteudo-da-paginacao').html(response)
         }
   });
})
```

## atualização

O autor da pergunta me questionou a respeito do conteúdo carregar a mesma página, e portanto, ele precisa de carregar apenas a `div`, e não todo o conteúdo.

Tem como usar a função `load` do jQuery. Com ela é possível carregar apenas um elemento específico de uma determinada página. Veja:

```
$('.page-link').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var url = $(this).data('href');

   $( "#conteudo-da-pagina" ).load( url + " #conteudo-da-pagina" );

})
```

Documentação do [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Obrigada Wallace, funcionou a paginação mas com um porem: Eu tenho duas colunas bootstrap, a esquerda um formulario de cadastro e a direita a lista do que ja foi cadastrado e que contem a paginação. Ao clicar na paginacação ( eu coloquei o id na tag table na tag `<table #conteudo-da-paginacao>`) a pagina inteira é duplicada la dentro, então a paginação esta funcionando mas o conteudo da tela inteira esta aparecendo na tag `table`

Comment: `var url = $(this).data('href');` vai retornar a tela inteira dentro de `#conteudo-da-paginacao` como faço para na variavel `url` pegar apenas o proprio id `#conteudo-da-paginacao` dentro da url e responder nesse mesmo `id`?

Comment: @Gislef tem como sim. $(response).find('#conteudo-da-paginacao').html()

Comment: substituo `$('#conteudo-da-paginacao').html(response)` por  `$(response).find('#conteudo-da-paginacao').html()`? desta forma não funcionou os botões ficaram sem ação

Comment: `$('#conteudo-da-paginacao').html($(response).find('#conteudo-da-paginacao').html())`. Você está inserido a mesma página, porém apenas a parte do `#conteudo`. No jQuery tem outras forma de fazer, vou dar uma relembrada. Só um minuto

Comment: Wallace, o resultado esta sendo o mesmo com o load, estou tentando seguir as dicas em respostas de uma pergunta no SOen [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300332/jquery-find-on-data-from-ajax-call-is-returning-object-object-instead), tentei filter no lugar de find por exemplo mas ainda não resolveu

Comment: Muito obrigada Wallace, consegui resolver assim: `var html = $('<div />', {html : response}).find('#content-of-table').html();
           $('#content-of-table').html( html )`  minha pergunta no SOen [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134303/ajax-find-filter-or-another/46134569?noredirect=1#comment79231905_46134569) Mas sua resposta fez a paginação ajax funcionar então vou marcar como correta

Comment: Ah! Bacana, cara! Desculpe não ter respondido, eu estava trabalhando :\. Que bom que conseguiu!